# Ocean plane shader with transparency

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, modifiers, shaders, ocean-simulation

I've made this ocean scene following a tutorial.

I want the shader to be transparent so I can see sharks or whatever though the water.
But adding transmission doesn't seem to work. And since it's a plane I also can't use volume absorption (I think)

Any suggestions?

My scene:
[image]

Reference:
[image]

Comment: In the reference, there is an ocean floor. Tried that?

Comment: yes but still cant see through the transmission pricinpled shader

Comment: Could you please share the tutorial? I've been looking for one like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't so much about Blender as physics.

1. Real ocean water is very light. Like *almost white*.
2. Aim your camera more downwards, to decrease reflections.
3. Add a shallow seabed to better control your ocean color.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ahh yes changing the diffuse color from black to light and adding the seabed did the trick. Thank you!! Also isnt water rougness just zero? maybe put 0.3 in transmission rougness makes more sense. But maybe I'm wrong

Comment: You're right, the roughness should probably be lower, but since there's a rough bump map, it doesn't make a difference here :).

Comment: Also maybe you know this but, why does changing the base color change the way it looks? I thought transmissive materials ignore the base color?

Comment: They don't ignore it :). *Transmission* is not *transparency*. It works the same as glass/water and gives a slight color tint. It also reflects environment colors, even when base color is pure white.

Answer (score 1):

To add transparency, push the "Transmission" slider towards the right under the "Principled BDSF" shader (The default shader). Make sure you are on Cycles.

Comment: Hello :). While this is not bad advice, I'm pretty sure the material in question is already at full Transmission. Also, transmission and transparency are slightly different things :).

Comment: yes it already was at full transmission!